# Import a plugin in Vue from local file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i want add a vue panel in my project  : vue-black-dashboard
in documentation :

> Vue Black Dashboard is built as Vue plugin so you can simply import it
>   and use it.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import DashboardPlugin from '@/plugins/blackDashboard'
Vue.use(DashboardPlugin);
```

but i dont know where paste vue-black-dashboard folder
how i can import it to my project
thanks

Comment: I will need more information in order to answer your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to import it and use in a `local component`, just import it in `component`.

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import DashboardPlugin from '@/plugins/blackDashboard'
Vue.use(DashboardPlugin);
export default {
}
</script>
```

If you want to import it and use globally, just import it in `main.js`.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import DashboardPlugin from '@/plugins/blackDashboard'
Vue.use(DashboardPlugin);
```

Comment: I still have the same error... I don't understand how the blackDashboard is downloaded/grabed. My pugin folder only contain vuetify.js

Answer (score 0):

hello thanks for your answer

```
import DashboardPlugin from '@/plugins/blackDashboard'
```

where is the @ in this address ? 
i want use this template in specify route of **my project**
when i import it in main.js

> This dependency was not found:
>
> - @/plugins/blackDashboard in ./src/main.js
>
> To install it, you can run: npm install --save
>   @/plugins/blackDashboard

Answer (score 0):

How's your plugin file look like? I have a similar issue with having plugins in separate files in /plugins directory and importing them to main.js

What I'm trying to achieve is better structure of plugins to keep them in separate files in folder plugins, rather than storing all the code in main.js
Not sure is it allowed or is it a good practice.

Plugins folder: plugins/toastification.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Toast from 'vue-toastification'
import 'vue-toastification/dist/index.css'

const options = {
  position: 'bottom-right'
}

Vue.use(Toast, options)

// export default new Toast() - got error while exporting but it works somehow without export default I don't know why
```

Part of main.js

```
// plugins
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import i18n from './plugins/i18n'
import toastification from './plugins/toastification'
import logger from './plugins/logger'

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  i18n,
  toastification,
  logger,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```